# python adding binary number

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

There is an unexpected output when I am dealing with binary number in Python 3.

We can easily convert any integer to binary by built-in bin() function. For example:

```
>>>bin(4243125)
```

Here's the issue when I try to add 2 binary function:

```
>>>bin(x)+bin(y)
```

The output is concatenation of two binary number, not addition of binary number. The output of binary function has become a string.

Addition in a binary function works fine:

```
>>>bin(x+y)
```

And try to add two binary number without bin() is viable too:

```
>>>0b100+0b10111
```

What is the reasons/purposes of setting a bin() output to a string?

Comment: Two reasons: 1. almost all Python numeric literals are in base 10, so `101` is *one hundred and one*, not *five*, and 2. (the exception, in Python 2.x only) a leading `0` means octal, so `0101 == 65`. Therefore, to avoid confusion, `bin` returns a string prefixed with `0b`.

Comment: Integers in Python are *already* stored in binary (well, technically, they're stored in either base 2**15 or base 2**30, but close enough).  The internal binary is converted to a decimal string for display (e.g., by `str` or `repr`).  What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Then why is it able to compute the 'str' type of binary number? Like 0b101+0b1 but not bin()+bin().

Comment: You're thinking about this wrongly:  abstractly, an integral number is just a number - it doesn't *have* a base.  There's no such thing as a "decimal integer" or a "binary integer".  There are decimal and binary *representations* of integers, and those are strings, not numbers.  Again, what is it that you want to achieve here?  What's the real problem you want to solve?

Comment: In somehow returning 'digits' in string type, isn't it interrupting further process?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for the explanation, I think I need another function to achieve as the answer below.

Comment: Well yes: once you've converted to a *string* representation, doing *numeric* work is more awkward.  But that's not a problem: if you want to do numeric calculations, keep your values as numbers.  If you want to do string processing on the *representations* of those numbers in a particular base, convert to a string (e.g., with `bin` or `oct` or `hex` or `str`).  One more time: **what are you trying to achieve here**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bin`, like `hex`, converts a decimal to a string literal representing the number in that base.

If you want to add 2 numbers together simply do so:

```
x = 10
y = 2
x + y
```

If you want to take binary strings as input and add them together convert them back from string literals with `int` base 2, like this:

```
x = bin(10)
y = bin(2)
int(x, 2) + int(y, 2)
```

If you're looking to do bitwise operations look at the Python bitwise operators:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators